# Account for MultiPolygons with geopandas.apply

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, multipolygons

How do I amend the following python code: that determines the number of sides/edges of a polygon; to account for `MultiPolygons`? *---interiors aren't necessary. exteriors only please.*
Without looping would be appreciated.
Data can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793889/reorganize-sides-edges-into-their-appropriate-polygons)

```py
edges = fp.geometry.apply(lambda x: len(x.exterior.coords)) - 1
edges

0    5
1    4
2    4
3    4
Name: geometry, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the geometry is an instance of `MultiPolygon` and if so convert the `MultiPolygon` to a list of `Polygon`s, calculate the number of edges for each, and then `sum` the total:

```
edges = fp.geometry.apply(lambda x: (
    len(x.exterior.coords) - 1
    if not isinstance(x, MultiPolygon) 
    else sum([len(poly.exterior.coords) - 1 for poly in list(x.geoms)])
))
```

You might also consider using  `shapely.get_num_points` and `shapely.get_parts` so your code is more explicit in what it is doing:

```
from shapely import get_num_points, get_parts
edges = fp.geometry.apply(lambda x: (
    get_num_points(x.exterior) - 1
    if not isinstance(x, MultiPolygon) 
    else sum([get_num_points(poly.exterior) - 1 for poly in get_parts(x)])
))
```